# How to show the application design window in android studio?

Tags: java, android-studio, sdk, java-13

I downloaded Android Studio a few days ago but I have a problem in the application design window that does not appear when I open the xml file or any other file as the image appears below it knowing that I have the latest version of Android Studio and the jdk
[Android Studio problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R59DC.png)

Comment: Do you get displayed your code?

Comment: Yes, but it appears as xml code and does not show the design window where I'm supposed to put buttons and layouts and....

Comment: Look at the image I added bellow, you have the answer there.

Answer (score 0):

If what I understand is correct, look at this image and click the middle button. This should display both the code and the xml preview.
[image]

Comment: I closed the project and started a new android studio project and the problem has been solved Thank you